# How do I fix this URL mapping problem? The pages are being displayed but the url is incorrect

Tags: python, django, django-urls

In this django app, I am trying to go to a specific page but the route it takes is not the correct one. Can you please tell me what am I doing wrong.

Ex. From http://127.0.0.1:8000 I am trying to go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/register but it takes me to http://127.0.0.1:8000/dashboard/register.

The http://127.0.0.1:8000/register link is working fine though if I enter it manually.

views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.

def home(request):
    return render(request, 'formfiller/home.html')

def register(request):
    return render(request, 'formfiller/signup.html')

def login(request):
    return render(request, 'formfiller/login.html')

def download(request):
    return render(request, 'formfiller/download.html')

def forgotpw(request):
    return render(request, 'formfiller/forgotpw.html')

def learnmore(request):
    return render(request, 'formfiller/learnmore.html')

def dashboard(request):
    return render(request, 'formfiller/dashboard.html')

def success(request):
    return HttpResponse("Your account has been successfully created.")
```

urls.py (for the app)

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('register', views.register, name='signup'),
    path('login', views.login, name='login'),
    path('download', views.download, name='download'),
    path('forgotpw', views.forgotpw, name='forgotpw'),
    path('learnmore', views.learnmore, name='learnmore'),
    path('dashboard', views.dashboard, name='dashboard'),
    path('success', views.success, name='success'),
]
```

urls.py (for the main project)

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('formfiller.urls')),
    path('register/', include('formfiller.urls')),
    path('login/', include('formfiller.urls')),
    path('download/', include('formfiller.urls')),
    path('forgotpw/', include('formfiller.urls')),
    path('learnmore/', include('formfiller.urls')),
        path('success/', include('formfiller.urls')),
        path('dashboard/', include('formfiller.urls')),
]
```

Comment: Please mark the answer as accepted if it's correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `include('formfiller.urls')` only once.

urls.py (for the app)

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('register', views.register, name='signup'),
    path('login', views.login, name='login'),
    path('download', views.download, name='download'),
    path('forgotpw', views.forgotpw, name='forgotpw'),
    path('learnmore', views.learnmore, name='learnmore'),
    path('dashboard', views.dashboard, name='dashboard'),
    path('success', views.success, name='success'),
]
```

urls.py (for the main project)

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('formfiller.urls')),
]
```

Comment: Thanks so much for helping out.